# How to mount an rsync-copied partition combined from two source partitions

Tags: linux, rsync, partitioning, mount, ext4

My PC is running ArchLinux. My PC has two hard disks, /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. sda is the source disk and contains all my files. sdb is the destination disk and is currently empty. My purpose is to make a copy of sda to sdb, and also make sdb another bootable ArchLinux installation.

sda has three partitions: sda1 for /boot, sda2 for /, sda3 for /home. Here is its /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda2   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
/dev/sda1   /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2
/dev/sda3   /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2
```

I formatted sdb to two partitions only: sdb1 for /boot and sdb2 for /. I used rsync to copy sda1 to sdb1, as well as sda2 and sda3 to sdb2. And then I also updated the UEFI bootloader and /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sdb2   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
/dev/sdb1   /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2
```

The problem is, when I booted from sdb, both sdb1 and sdb2 were automatically mounted, but /home is empty. My personal home directory was not found under /home. Why is that?

Later I rebooted from sda and then manually mounted sdb2 and confirmed that my personal home directory was in /home.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you boot from /dev/sda and mount /dev/sdb2 /disk etc. you can navigate to /disk/home/<your_user> and this directory contains your files?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that. When I booted from /dev/sda and mounted /dev/sdb2, all my files were in /mnt/home/<my_user>. This means rsync really copied my home directory to the new disk.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I forgot to update /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf, so the gummiboot bootloader actually loaded /dev/sda2 instead of /dev/sdb2. And because sda2 did not contain /home/, so /home/ was not found.